# Execute code repeatedly during animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen something like this in Java and I'm wondering if it's there something similar in JavaScript/jQuery. Basically I have a function with an animation and a code that runs at the end of it:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function(){
    lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});
```

However, I want this code to be updated during the animation e.g.: if the user is `500px`, I want `lastScrollTop` to become 450,400,300,200,100,50,0

Is there a way to keep my variable updated during the animation?

Comment: What about the `step` or `progress` function of `animate`?

Comment: no idea what they are. will look them up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step) or `progress` of the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method:

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, {
    duration: 'slow',
    step: function(now, fx) {
        lastScrollTop = now; //Get the current scroll amount.
    },
    complete: function() {
        lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    }
});
```

- *`now`*: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
- *`fx`*: a reference to the jQuery.fx prototype object, which contains a number of properties such as elem for the animated element, start and end for the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and prop for the property being animated.

Comment: this works, however I have a little problem I just pasted it in the console, and the complete solution fires twice. (I tried it with a console.log). Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you paste a [**jsfiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so I can see what you are experiencing?

Comment: I found the problem, selecting both html and body fired the event twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use step if you want to get the value **before** the animation happens, and use progress if you want the value **after** it happens. Something like this:

```
$('html,body').animate(
    {scrollTop: 0}, 
    {
        'slow',
        step: function(currentTop){
            console.log (currentTop)
        }
    }, 
    function(){
        lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    }
);
```